# GraphX - How to get all connected vertices from vertexId (not just the firsts adjacents)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

Considering this graph:

[Exemple graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRuM5.png)

How can I get all connected vertices from a vertexID?

For example, from `VertexId 5`, it should return 5-3-7-8-10

`CollectNeighbors` only returns the first adjacent ones.

I'm trying to use `pregel`, but I don't know how to start from a specific vertex. I don't want to calculate all the nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just noticed that the graph is directed. then you can use the code of the shortest path example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#pregel-api). if the distance of a specific node is not infinity then you can reach this node.

or there is a better idea you can modify the shortest path algorithm to satisfy your needs.

```
  import org.apache.spark.graphx.{Graph, VertexId}
  import org.apache.spark.graphx.util.GraphGenerators

  // A graph with edge attributes containing distances
  val graph: Graph[Long, Double] =
    GraphGenerators.logNormalGraph(sc, numVertices = 100).mapEdges(e => e.attr.toDouble)

  val sourceId: VertexId = 42 // The ultimate source
  // Initialize the graph such that all vertices except the root have canReach = false.
  val initialGraph: Graph[Boolean, Double]  = graph.mapVertices((id, _) => id == sourceId)
  val sssp = initialGraph.pregel(false)(
    (id, canReach, newCanReach) => canReach || newCanReach, // Vertex Program
    triplet => {  // Send Message
      if (triplet.srcAttr && !triplet.dstAttr) {
        Iterator((triplet.dstId, true))
      } else {
        Iterator.empty
      }
    },
    (a, b) => a || b // Merge Message
  )
  println(sssp.vertices.collect.mkString("\n"))
```

Comment: The connected components seem to connect to the lowest vertex id. The result will be (8,2), (12,2), (5,2), (10,2), (2,2), (3,2), (7,2) because the lowest vertex is 2. How can I specify the minimum to 5 and not include the (12,2)?

Comment: please check my latest update, I added a better idea.

Comment: After inspection, strangely, it only works for my example, but it does not seem to work for the generated graph, because the result is always 100 true no matter the VertexId. Logically, the number of vertices should be less than 100?

Comment: Make sure the graph is directed.